# Combining the output of a aggregate function over a group in a Dataframes and output of a search over the entire Dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to compare a grouped by list both within the group and the complete Dataframes.

I have created a Dataframes with some trip data :
Id, Sourced Address, Destination Address, BkId, Vendor, Rate, Converted, BidRank, SCity, DCity, VType, MM, YYY

I am running a data analysis on this to find patterns.

One of the patterns I am looking for is 
For each Vendor, the comparison between Converted and Won over all Source/Destination/VType (**Familiarity Factor**), and Converted and Won/Not Won over specific Source/Destination/VType (**Preference Factor**)
I also want to summarise the Rates over different combinations of Source/Destination/VType (**Rate Factor** in terms of Median/Max/Min/Count).
I also want to establish the rate factor in the last month (**Specific Rate Factor** again in terms of Median/Max/Min/Count).
I want to be able to sort over any of the four factors or specific parts of the 3td factor, say Median/Count preference.

1. I did a group by and created a list of Vendors

```python
res1=cimsBid[(cimsBid['CVtype']=='32 FT Single-Axle 7MT - HCV') & >(cimsBid['SCity']=='Chennai') & (cimsBid['Dcity']=='Gurugram')].groupby('Vendor')
```

2. Getting The first 2 factors:

```python
    #capture all vendors from the grouped by tuple
    L1Res1=[]
    for name,group in res1:
        L1Res1.append(name)
    #count for familiarity, preference, history
    L1Won=0;
    L1Bid=0;
    L1WonRV=0;
    Results=[]
    for i in range(len(L1Res1)):
        L1Won=len(cimsBid[(cimsBid['Vendor']==L1Res1[i]) & (cimsBid['Converted']=='Yes')])
    L1Bid=len(cimsBid[(cimsBid['Vendor']==L1Res1[i]) & (cimsBid['SCity']=='Chennai') & (cimsBid['Dcity']=='Gurugram') & (cimsBid['CVtype']=='32 FT Single-Axle 7MT - HCV')]) 
    L1WonRV=len(cimsBid[(cimsBid['Vendor']==L1Res1[i]) & (cimsBid['SCity']=='Chennai') & (cimsBid['Dcity']=='Gurugram') & (cimsBid['CVtype']=='32 FT Single-Axle 7MT - HCV') & (cimsBid['BidRank']==1)])
    Results.append(L1Res1[i], L1Won, L1Bid, L1WonRV)
```

3. Aggregating over the grouped by data

```python
    res1.agg({'Rate':[sum,min,max,np.median],'BookingID':"count"})
```

I now have two disparate data output:
One is a list of lists :

```python
    [['BABA KASI NATH ROADWAYS', 23, 2, 2], ['Choudhary Container Service Naveen D', 3, 1, 1], ['KULDEEP CONTAINER SERVICES', 7, 1, 0], ['NTEX TRANSPORTATION SERVICES PRIVATE LIMITED  ', 80, 2, 0], ['Payal Cargo Carrier', 28, 1, 1], ['RUTE LOGISTICS PRIVATE LIMITED', 55, 1, 1], ['S M ENTERPEISES', 2, 2, 0], ['S.M EXPRESS', 2, 1, 0], ['SREE BALAJI COINTAINER CARRIER', 19, 1, 0], ['Sharma Transport Company', 11, 1, 1], ['TAMNNA CARGO MOVERS', 2, 2, 1], ['VASHU CONTAINER SERVICE CHENNAI ', 5, 1, 1]]
```

and the other is the aggregate function output.

I dont quite understand how to combine the two elegantly.  How do I make a new data frame with the list I have and the aggregate output?
Agg Output:

```
                                             Rate           BookingID
                                sum min max median             count
Vendor                  
BABA KASI NATH ROADWAYS.    118000.0    57000.0 61000.0 59000.0 2
Choudhary Container S        60000.0    60000.0 60000.0 60000.0 1
KULDEEP CONTAINER SERVICES   60000.0    60000.0 60000.0 60000.0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried shape on agg output and realised it is already a DataFrame!
SO I just added the "Vendor" names back as a column:

```Python
out1=res1.agg({'Rate':[sum,min,max,np.median],'BookingID':"count"})
out1['Vendor']=L1Res1
out1.columns

MultiIndex(levels=[['Rate', 'BookingID', 'Vendor'], ['count', 'max', 'median', 'min', 'sum', '']],
           codes=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2], [4, 3, 1, 2, 0, 5]])
```

Now the question changes to how to access data over multi index levels.